# How to create a daily copy value from a range a date in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've a date with the specific value. I need to range into a daily date from the previous date will have the same value.

```
    dates bi7dr Month Year Day
 1: 2023-01-19  5.75     1 2023  19
 2: 2022-12-22  5.50    12 2022  22
 3: 2022-11-17  5.25    11 2022  17
 4: 2022-10-20  4.75    10 2022  20
 5: 2022-09-22  4.25     9 2022  22
 6: 2022-08-23  3.75     8 2022  23
 7: 2022-07-21  3.50     7 2022  21
 8: 2022-06-23  3.50     6 2022  23
 9: 2022-05-24  3.50     5 2022  24
```

How can I generate a daily data from the table above. I specific looking for the data will gonna be look like

```
until today 5.75
2023-01-21  5.75
2023-01-20  5.75
2023-01-19  5.75
2023-01-18  5.50
2023-01-17  5.50
...........
2022-12-22  5.50
2022-12-21  5.25
2022-12-20  5.25
until the latest data
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: "I need to range into a daily date from the previous date will have the same value." This sentence is hard to understand

Comment: Look at the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt <- dt[, .(dates, bi7dr)][, dates := as.Date(dates)][CJ(dates = seq(min(dates), Sys.Date(), by = "days")), on = .(dates)]

setnafill(dt, type = "locf", cols = "bi7dr")
setorder(dt, -dates)

dt[]

# dates bi7dr
# 1: 2023-01-25  5.75
# 2: 2023-01-24  5.75
# 3: 2023-01-23  5.75
# 4: 2023-01-22  5.75
# 5: 2023-01-21  5.75
# ---                 
#   243: 2022-05-28  3.50
# 244: 2022-05-27  3.50
# 245: 2022-05-26  3.50
# 246: 2022-05-25  3.50
# 247: 2022-05-24  3.50
```